# Insert a nested document into a DocumentDB doc using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure-cosmosdb, document-database

what's the best way to insert a nested document into the following?

```
{
    "id": "3af62b94-2031-4b85-9fd3-e13e7217d382",
    "Email": "test@ingeniuus.com",
    "Name": "test",
    "OrgRoles": null,
    "UpdatedDate": "2017-11-10T10:49:11.1962998Z",
    "CreatedDate": "2017-11-10T10:49:05.6247018Z",
    "IsDeleted": true,
    "_rid": "KFokAOUDHwEtAAAAAAAAAA==",
    "_self": "dbs/KFokAA==/colls/KFokAOUDHwE=/docs/KFokAOUDHwEtAAAAAAAAAA==/",
    "_etag": "\"00001e00-0000-0000-0000-5a0584270000\"",
    "_attachments": "attachments/",
    "_ts": 1510310951
}
```

Ideally I want to append after OrgRoles so that the doc would look like:

```
{
    "id": "3af62b94-2031-4b85-9fd3-e13e7217d382",
    "Email": "test@ingeniuus.com",
    "Name": "test",
    "OrgRoles": null,
    "Devices": [
             "ID": "765476547",
             "name": "myDevice"
     ],
    "UpdatedDate": "2017-11-10T10:49:11.1962998Z",
    "CreatedDate": "2017-11-10T10:49:05.6247018Z",
    "IsDeleted": true,
    "_rid": "KFokAOUDHwEtAAAAAAAAAA==",
    "_self": "dbs/KFokAA==/colls/KFokAOUDHwE=/docs/KFokAOUDHwEtAAAAAAAAAA==/",
    "_etag": "\"00001e00-0000-0000-0000-5a0584270000\"",
    "_attachments": "attachments/",
    "_ts": 1510310951
}
```

I'm currently using the Node.js DocumentDB client to do my searches so would like to continue to use this but can't seem to see a push or update or equivalent method in there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call `readDocument`, make updates locally, then update it using `replaceDocument`.